# SpotifyAPI in spotifyplayer

Tags: reactjs, spotify

So I'm having a bit of struggle with the SpotifyPlayer since they made it premium. I wonder if anything that I can play the spotify player in other ways without using the `react-spotify-web-playback`...

Although  this is the code...

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import SpotifyPlayer from 'react-spotify-web-playback'
function Player({accessToken,trackUri}) {

    const [play,setPlay] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => setPlay(true),[trackUri])

    if (!accessToken) return null

    return (
        <SpotifyPlayer 
            token={accessToken}
            showSaveIcon
            callback={state => {
                if (!state.isSaved) setPlay(false)
            }}
            play={true}
            uris = {trackUri ? [trackUri] : []}
        ></SpotifyPlayer>
    )
}

export default Player
```

That I follow in the last tutorial I saw...but the SpotifyPlayer is premium so can anyone tell me or whatever can I create an alternative or another way to get the spotify player? or something else. Thanks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xcet6msf3eE

Answer (score 0):

You can use specific links that will play the album directly after clicking on it: [demo link](https://open.spotify.com/track/0dEIca2nhcxDUV8C5QkPYb?context=spotify:album:4m2880jivSbbyEGAKfITCa&go=1)

```
https://open.spotify.com/track/0dEIca2nhcxDUV8C5QkPYb?context=spotify:album:4m2880jivSbbyEGAKfITCa&go=1
https://open.spotify.com/track/ID_FIRST_TRACK?context=spotify:album:ALBUM_ID&go=1
```